# Character to use for the onomotapoeic sound "choong!"

Tags: character-identification

"Choong!" is the sound of something taking off or being launched. I'm trying to find out if there is a character for this sound as "choong" is not used for any regular character.

Not to be confused with 冲, the oo sound is long and more like the "u" in put rather than "oo" in spoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `噌`, or cēnɡ (the equivalent of "whoosh").

As in:

> “噌”的一聲，火柴劃着了.

Answer (score 2):

Although this doesn't answer your question specifically to "choong", I found an interesting PDF about [onomatopoeic words in Chinese](http://www.pinyin.info/readings/yin_binyong/o09_onomatopoeia.pdf) with many examples divided according to their structure. If you want I can transcribe them here.